# Call FormDialog from Botbuilder in Loop

Tags: c#, .net, azure-language-understanding, botframework

Hy, is there any option to create a second FormDialog in a Luis-Match function.
My LUIS instance find one or more drinks, like:

- I need a [water].
- I need a [tea] and a [coke].

If there are more than one entity, i would ask for every entity additional informations.

```
[LuisIntent("Drinks")]
public async Task Bestellung(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    entities1 = ... // entities for first drink
    entities2 = ... // entities for second drink

    orderForm1 = new FormDialog<Drink>(new Drink(), formFunction, FormOptions.PromptInStart, entities1);
    await context.Forward(orderForm1, afterFormFunction);
    orderForm2 = new FormDialog<Drink>(new Drink(), formFunction, FormOptions.PromptInStart, entities2);
    await context.Forward(orderForm2, afterFormFunction);
}
```

I get a Exception: "invalid need: expected Call, have Poll"

Where is my fault? Thanks for Help!

Comment: I mean context.Call! Sorry my fault. But the Answer is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to the second form dialog must be done in the `afterFormFunction` `ResumeAfter<T>` method and not after the first `context.Forward`.

After the first form dialog ends, execution continue in the `afterFormFunction`.